# Store line number and number of occurances per word using hash perl

Tags: perl, hash, key

I am reading in a file word by word (where a file contains lines of words) and storing each word in to a hash.  I would like to store the number of occurrences as well as which line the word was found on (note:  I will be sorting the hash based on the words themselves, as shown in the code)

I have (unworking) (assume that the words-array has word stored correctly, with no special characters, and is lowercase):

```
my %wordlist;
my $line = 0;

foreach my $word (@words) {
  $line++;

  if (exists $wordlist{$word}) {
      $wordlist{$word} += 1;
      $wordlist{$line} = $wordlist{$line} . ", $line";
  }
  else {
      $wordlist{$word} = 1;
      $wordlist{$line} = "$line";
  }  
}
```

And later I try to print $wordlist{$line} as a string, inside a loop containing:

```
printf "%${length}s: %4d times, on lines %s\n", $key, $wordlist{$key}, $wordlist{$line};
```

When running, I get the error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in printf at ./wc.pl line 105, <FILE> line 20.
someWord:    2 time(s), line(s)
```

where line 20 is the exit statement

Comment: Whats the error? Have you used Data::Dumper on %wordlist to verify it looks like you expect it to?

Comment: I am not familiar with Data::dumper.  I will add the error to the original post

Comment: You're declaring `my $line = 0;` but incrementing `$line_num++;`. You also have a typo: `$wordlist{$linem}`

Comment: The typos were in code translation to make it more readable for everyone, thank you for pointing it out.  Fixed!

Comment: also `wordlist` vs `wordList`. Adding `use strict` and `use warnings` would highlight this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$wordlist{$line}   # Line data for each line
```

should be

```
$wordline{$word}   # Line data for each word
```

---

It's generally a bad practice to format your output before it's time to output. Here is no exception.

```
if (exists $wordlist{$word}) {
    ++$wordlist{$word};
    push @{ $wordline{$word} }, $line;
}
else {
    ++$wordlist{$word};
    push @{ $wordline{$word} }, $line;
}
```

which of course simplifies to

```
++$wordlist{$word};
push @{ $wordline{$word} }, $line;
```

In the `printf`, you'd use

```
join(', ', @{ $wordline{$word} })
```

---

But `$wordlist{$word}` is just the number of elements in `@{ $wordline{$word} }`, so it's completely unneeded. Just use

```
0+@{ $wordline{$word} }
```

instead of

```
$wordlist{$word}
```

---

So you end up with

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( max );

my %wordlines;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   push @{ $wordlines{$_} }, $.;
}

my $max_len_p1 = 1 + max map length, keys %wordlines;
my $max_count_len = max map length(0+@$_), values %wordlines;
my $format = "%-${max_len_p1}s %${max_count_len}d times, on lines %s\n";

for my $word (
   sort { @{ $wordlines{$b} } <=> @{ $wordlines{$a} } || $a cmp $b }
      keys %wordlines
) {
   printf($format,
      "$word:",
      0+@{ $wordlines{$word} },
      join(', ', @{ $wordlines{$word} }),
   );
}
```

Input:

```
cat
house
stair
chari
stair
mouse
stool
cat
hat
```

Output:

```
cat:   2 times, on lines 1, 8
stair: 2 times, on lines 3, 5
chari: 1 times, on lines 4
hat:   1 times, on lines 9
house: 1 times, on lines 2
mouse: 1 times, on lines 6
stool: 1 times, on lines 7
```

Comment: I was not sure how else to do it.  Could you explain how to modify the printf with the join a bit further, and explain how it works?

Comment: Simply take out `$wordline{$word}` and put in `join(', ', @{ $wordline{$word} })`.

Comment: After studying the code for a bit, I understand it more.  But for the `push @{ $wordlines{$_} }, $.;` line, how can this push a single word from a line, rather than the whole line?  Such as, if the input file were:

`cat house stair
chari stair mouse
stool cat hat`

edit:  That didn't format at all.  Basically, 3 words per line with 3 lines

Comment: `for my $word (split) { }` or `for my $word (/(\S+)/g) { }`

Comment: Hopefully this question will have given you some experience for writing your next question. Some parts were vague so assumptions were made. It helps to clearly lay out your problem, so in this case, showing the input and what you expect as the output would have been helpful along with your code. So the inital question said you read the file word by word, So the assumption here was that we would process word by word. Then asking about multiple words on the same line changed the nature of the question slightly

Comment: Yes, it has helped in that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following example, it should give you a good base to start out and modify.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = <>;
my %wordlist;
my $line = 0;

foreach my $word (@words) {
        chomp($word);
        push (@{$wordlist{$word}}, ++$line);
}

foreach my $word (keys %wordlist){
        my $count = @{$wordlist{$word}};
        my $lines = join (', ',@{$wordlist{$word}});
        printf ("%-10s: %4d times, on lines %s\n", $word, $count, $lines);
}
```

This example uses perls autovivification to create the data structure on the fly if it is not already defined. In essence, every word it reads it will push the line number on to the array of that word key in the hash. If that word has never been seen then autovivifaction will create the key in the hash and simiarly create the array in the hash value.

Then for the output we can get the word since its the key, we can get the number of times it was seen by couting the number of line numbers that exist in the array of the hash value, and we can make a string of the line numbers using join.

then we can just print out these values with printf. so a word list of

```
cat
house
stair
chari
stair
mouse
stool
cat
hat
```

will produce an output of

```
mouse     :    1 times, on lines 6
cat       :    2 times, on lines 1, 8
hat       :    1 times, on lines 9
stool     :    1 times, on lines 7
chari     :    1 times, on lines 4
stair     :    2 times, on lines 3, 5
house     :    1 times, on lines 2
```

Comment: Instead of a comment saying thanks, if this helped please vote it up. thanks.

Comment: @Babals Ah ok sorry, didnt realise.